# How to hide secret keys and access ID from aws lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to hide my secret keys and access ID from aws lambda function code written in python. How do I do it?

I have hardcoded it in my code but it is not a good practice. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be do not use IAM keys and IAM secrets for your Lambda. Use the Lambda role instead.

Give the permissions to the [Lambda role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) that the IAM user would have had.

It is best practice to use IAM roles for a number of reasons:

- It uses temporary credentials
- No need to hardcode credentials you do not want to be exposed
- No deployments needed for key changes, just midy the policies of the existing role.

Your Lambda will always have a role attached, to use it rather than the IAM key/secret remove the credentials from the code source like so

Before

```
 s3_client = boto3.client('s3', 
   aws_access_key_id=$KEY, 
   aws_secret_access_key=$SECRET_KEY, 
   region_name=REGION_NAME
)
```

After

```
 s3_client = boto3.client('s3', 
   region_name=REGION_NAME
)
```

Comment: Can you include your code and validate your Lambda role includes permissions? :)

Comment: AWSLambdaFullAccess, AmazonS3FullAccess,AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess,AmazonESFullAccess My lambda role have these permission. Do I need to add any other?

Comment: Those permissions should definitely work, how does the Labda code look?

Comment: Can you remove the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` arguments for all clients :)

Comment: Can you add the code to the question with formatting so I can try to reproduce :)

Comment: @PranayKhare Make sure that the IAM Role has been associated with your Lambda function. This is in the **Basic settings** section, under **Execution role**.

Answer (score 0):

> I have hardcoded it in my code but it is not a good practice. Is there any way to achieve this??

Yes, there is a better way.

You should use [AWS Lambda execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) to give your function necessary permissions to do its job.